# Syntax tree software

Tags: syntax, resource-request, software

Does anybody know a good software for creating syntax tree diagrams like this ?[image]

Comment: That’s not a linguistic syntax tree. It’s an [abstract syntax tree representing computer source code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371453/Visual-AST-for-ANTLR-Generated-Parser-Output) (link describes how this particular AST was created, in C#).

Answer (score 5):

For typesetting, the `forest` package for LaTeX is quite good, and has a lot of presets built in for linguistics purposes (syntax trees, autosegmental trees, etc).

[image: LaTeX forest tree]

Source:

```
[CP
    [CP
        [that]
        [TP
            [DP
                [{the fact that...},roof]
            ]
            [\ibar{T}
                [{is clear to all},roof]
            ]
(etc)
```

For simpler tasks, like making trees for answers here, I use [jsSyntaxTree](https://ironcreek.net/syntaxtree/). It's not very customizable but is very fast and straightforward to use.

[image: jsSyntaxTree tree]

Source:

```
[TP [T might] [AuxP [Aux have] [vP [v+V gone] [V t]]]]
```

Finally, if you're looking to generate them programmatically (e.g. test a automatic parser by printing out the trees it generates), [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/) is popular and has bindings for most programming languages.

[image: GraphViz tree]

Source:

```
   n002 [label="+"] ;
   n002 -- n003 ;
   n003 [label="*"] ;
   n003 -- n004 ;
   n004 [label="X"] ;
   n003 -- n005 ;
   n005 [label="-"] ;
   n005 -- n006 ;
(etc)
```

([Via](https://graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/Genetic_Programming.html))